# css3 checkbox styling not working with extra input

Tags: css

I  want to style a checkbox using an image but because the checkbox is being generated with razor it creates an extra hidden input so the checkbox and the label are not sitting next to each other and therefore

input[type=checkbox] + label

no longer works as they are no longer adjacent sibling selectors.

Remove the hidden input and the styling works but this is not an option for me

Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/2434/

```
 .yesno input[type=checkbox] + label {
   background-image: url(http://placehold.it/40x40/ff6633/000000?text=yes);
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue with Razor before. I had to add another `+` selector in like so:

```
.yesno input[type=checkbox] + input + label {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/40x40/ff6633/000000?text=yes);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

you can see the working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/2437/

It's not the best but it was the easiest solution i found in the past :)

Or as @Lgson mentioned you could use the `~` selector.

`.yesno input[type=checkbox] ~ label`